# Trouble using Integrate as the model in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, fitting, data

I'm trying to fit a set of heat capacity data to the Debye model.

This is the sample dataset that I'm using:

```
dataset = {{2.05899, 0.0966062}, {2.06815, 0.0963254}, {2.11413, 
    0.0978416}, {2.16795, 0.0991946}, {2.22744, 0.100566}, {2.29526, 
    0.102113}, {2.37157, 0.103468}, {2.4522, 0.104557}, {2.5393, 
    0.106795}, {2.63797, 0.107489}, {2.75074, 0.110521}, {2.86724, 
    0.113042}, {2.98851, 0.114997}, {3.10926, 0.119145}, {3.23705, 
    0.12385}, {3.37318, 0.128375}, {3.51821, 0.134831}, {3.66603, 
    0.142051}, {3.82298, 0.151682}, {3.99139, 0.162452}, {4.16682, 
    0.175691}, {4.34705, 0.197153}, {4.53399, 0.216079}, {4.73028, 
    0.245886}, {4.93872, 0.276781}, {5.15496, 0.324267}};
R = 8.314;
$Assumptions = \[CapitalTheta]D > 0 && nD > 0;
```

I then make a function for the Debye model, as shown below. I think the issue is the integration limits.

```
CvD[Tt_, \[CapitalTheta]Dt_, nDt_] := 
  9 R nDt (Tt/\[CapitalTheta]Dt)^3*
   Integrate[(
    Exp[x]*x^4)/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, \[CapitalTheta]Dt/Tt}];
```

Here is where I set my starting parameters and attempt to call NonlinearModelFit.

```
coeffs = {\[CapitalTheta]D, nD};
startingpoints = {127, .9};
mixedCoeffs = {coeffs, startingpoints} // Transpose;

CpFit = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, {CvD[T, \[CapitalTheta]D, nD]}, 
  coeffs, T]
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be unless this approach won't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention that you get error messages like:

[image]

Now try:

```
{1/ΘD^374.826` nD T^3 (-((4 π^4)/15) + 
     1/((-1 + E^(ΘD/
         T)) T^4) (-E^((ΘD/T)) ΘD^4 - 
        4 T ΘD^3 Log[1 - E^(ΘD/T)] + 
        4 E^(ΘD/T)
          T ΘD^3 Log[1 - E^(ΘD/T)] + 
        12 (-1 + E^(ΘD/
           T)) T^2 ΘD^2 PolyLog[2, E^(ΘD/
          T)] - 24 (-1 + E^(ΘD/
           T)) T^3 ΘD PolyLog[3, E^(ΘD/
          T)] - 24 T^4 PolyLog[4, E^(ΘD/T)] + 
        24 E^(ΘD/T)
          T^4 PolyLog[4, E^(ΘD/
          T)]))} /. {ΘD -> 1, nD -> 1, T -> 8}


{24.9225 + 6.18925*10^-11 I}
```

This results in a complex number. I think this is due to numerical errors. Therefore, the fix is to wrap "CvD" in "Re" like:

```
CvD[Tt_, \[CapitalTheta]Dt_, nDt_] := 
  Re[9 R nDt (Tt/\[CapitalTheta]Dt)^3*
    Integrate[(Exp[x]*x^4)/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 
      0, \[CapitalTheta]Dt/Tt}]];
```

Now we get:

```
CpFit = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, {CvD[T, \[CapitalTheta]D, nD]}, 
  coeffs, T]
```

[image]

although with a warning.